# Offline Hyperlinks from pdf to a file in a flash drive

Tags: pdftex, hyperref

I am building a table in alphabetic order that displays names and information concerning them. I would like to make a "hyperlink" from the TeX pdf that would open pdf which lies in the same memory spot (a flash drive). 
Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. If the path of your TeX pdf is d:/path/to/your/tex.pdf then, you can do the hyperlink with the following command:

```
\href{run:d:/my folder/test.pdf}{The link to your file}
```